# SQL inner join on specified columns

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to use Inner join on 2 tables sharing same column name.
The first table is temp table but the column name equals the others table Primary key column name.
How can I join between them without changing the names of the column (in the temp table of course)?

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Apps] 
    INNER JOIN #statsForManagerApps on [Apps].[AppId] = #statsForManagerApps.AppId
     WHERE AppId IN 
     (SELECT AppId FROM [AppsForManagers] WHERE [Managerid] = @ManagerId) AND [Enabled]=1
```

This is how my join looks like. Using * because I need all data in Apps table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the table in your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE Apps.AppId IN
```

You can also alias the tables, as shown below:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Apps] App
INNER JOIN #statsForManagerApps on App.AppId = #statsForManagerApps.AppId
WHERE App.AppId IN 
(SELECT AppId FROM [AppsForManagers] WHERE [Managerid] = @ManagerId) AND [Enabled]=1
```

Comment: Getting from SQL : The multi-part identifier "App.AppId" could not be bound.

Comment: because its WHERE Apps.AppId IN
Works perfectly, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should specify all columns with table aliases as below

```
SELECT A.col1,A.col2, TA.col1,TA.col2  
FROM [dbo].[Apps] A
INNER JOIN #statsForManagerApps TA on A.AppId = TA.AppId
WHERE A.AppId IN (SELECT AppId FROM [AppsForManagers] WHERE [Managerid] = @ManagerId) 
AND A.Enabled=1
```

if yo really can't use table names (as you said 30 columns) try with below `select` statements instead of above:

```
SELECT *
```

or

```
SELECT A.*, TA.*
```

Comment: I afraid someone will say that, i have around 30 columns combined... no other way before i get into it?

Comment: @VeraGavriel Try my code with `select * from` or `select A.*,TA.* from`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use table aliases for the join.  This will also make the query much easier to read:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM [dbo].[Apps] a INNER JOIN
     #statsForManagerApps sfm
     on [Apps].[AppId] = sfm.AppId
WHERE a.AppId IN (SELECT AppId FROM [AppsForManagers] WHERE [Managerid] = @ManagerId) AND
      [Enabled]=1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying which AppId column to use:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Apps] 
INNER JOIN #statsForManagerApps 
  ON [Apps].[AppId] = #statsForManagerApps.AppId
WHERE [Apps].AppId IN 
  (    SELECT [AppsForManagers].AppId FROM [AppsForManagers] 
        WHERE [Managerid] = @ManagerId
  )
  AND [Enabled]=1
```